# How to add comments to fenced code block within doxygen documentation

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I am using fenced code blocks in Doxygen using the markdown syntax.  This makes it easy to add a simple code example, like this:

```
~~~~~{.cpp}
void doSomething()
   {
   }
~~~~~
```

When I try to add comments into the fenced code block using two forward slashes, Doxygen seems to remove the slashes.  So when I write this:

```
~~~~~{.cpp}
void doSomething()
   {
   // This function should do something
   }
~~~~~
```

I get this output:

```
void doSomething()
   {
This function should do something
   }
```

How can I tell Doxygen to keep the comments in the fenced code block?

**EDIT:**

The complete file looks like this (we use the standard Doxygen extension of .dox for documentation-only files):

```
/*!
\page PATTERN_SAMPLE Sample

~~~~~{.cpp}
void doSomething()
   {
   // This function should do something
   }
~~~~~
*/
```

The result looks like this:
[image: Result]

Comment: Can you show how the above markup is embedded in a comment block or .md file?

Comment: I've added the complete file contents in the question.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try with \code

```
  \code{.cpp}
  class Cpp {};
  \endcode
```

Comment: Indeed this works.  I knew that the \code existed, but I didn't know you could add {.cpp} after it.  However, {.cpp} doesn't seem to make a difference.  I tested it with a small for-loop, and it only seems to color the "for" keyword.  All other words (vector, int, push_back, main) are still shown in black.  Luckily, the comments work correctly with it (and they are colored as well).

Answer (score 6):

I encountered the same issue. No need to change code format. You can specify `STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS` as `NO`: this setting outputs the source code with the comment.

```
# Setting the STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS tag to YES will instruct doxygen to hide any
# special comment blocks from generated source code fragments. Normal, C++ and
# Fortran comments will always remain visible.
# The default value is: YES.

STRIP_CODE_COMMENTS    = NO
```